# Display aligned strings in ListBox Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to display the Strings aligned in the textbox but even if I use the same index for second column they are shifted. 
[image: unaligned text columns]

Answer (score 0):

For laying out a number of rows with column alignment, the [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/gridview-overview) is a good option.

> GridView view mode is one of the view modes for a ListView control. The GridView class and its supporting classes enable you and your users to view item collections in a table that typically uses buttons as interactive column headers. This topic introduces the GridView class and outlines its use.